# I want to find a good font combination based on existing design

Tags: website-design, typography

I am designing a mobile site for an existing website that was made in early 2000's.

The existing logo uses a bold version of Bodini with smaller text which uses a thin sans serif typeface. The existing site uses Georgia for body text.

The tone/mood of the website is elegant and deals with quality food products. The main colour palette is black, grey, and white.

I am new to design and excited about the challenge of typography, though I am finding it hard to get a good typeface scheme.

I want an elegant (fairly neutral) sans-serif typeface that works well with a bold Bodini style heading, and also plays well with Georgia style body text?

I am also looking for alternatives to Georgia for body text.

Reading articles there are lots of great tips and best practises but I am still struggling to make sense of all of the typefaces out there and make a good match.

Has anyone got any suggestions on what typefaces might be a good match? or what process they use for choosing typefaces and typeface combinations?

EDIT: I should also add that I am using web-fonts, and preferably free ones!

Comment: Georgia is a workhorse and is perhaps ideally left as-is. As for Bodoni, nearly any humanist sans should go OK with it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Humanist_sans-serif_typefaces

Comment: Umm... not today (Wikipedia's dark for the day).

Comment: disable java script and WIKIPEDIA will work :D

Comment: Or use something else for the day and support Wiki's protest. :)

Comment: "Disable javascript"??? *gasps, mops forehead, clutches chair for support*

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when I design it's a serif (Bodoni) and a sans(maybe arial or helvetica) with an occasional decorative font, eg. Lobster. You never really want to mix 2 different families of serifs(or sans). Remember, Simple is better.

I would drop the georgia though Bodoni web font will cost you as you can see [here](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/atf-bodoni/).
The list of free web fonts can be easily accessed [here](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

Familiarize yourself with fonts, it's mainly practice, you can even read articles from top typographers that will explain their choices.